# How to use less than or greater than symbol in JavaScript function in JSF page?

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf

I am new to JSF. I want to check a condition that a value is greater than zero in javascript function in JSF page. Normally it works in JavaScript, but in JSF page If I use `<` or `>` symbol means it displays an error like,

> The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or
>   markup.

Please any one give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, we have here also a search engine. It's rather easy to use. Click the input field on the right hand above, enter JSF as tag `[jsf]` and then paste the exact error message thereafter "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup". [The answers are there](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjsf%5D+The+content+of+elements+must+consist+of+well-formed+character+data+or+markup).

Comment: Move the JavaScript code outside the XHTML to its own js file and import this file to your XHTML page or enclose your JavaScript code within an ugly `<![CDATA[ ` block.

Answer (score 5):

Enclose your script with `CDATA` as below,

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
...
]]>
</script>
```

OR
Use HTML Entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`